Is it important to call `close()` on an file opened with `open()` if `flush()` is called after each write() operation?
I have read that it is important to call close() on a file which has been opened with open(filename, 'w'|'a') because otherwise changes made to the opened file may not be persisted. I believe this is due to buffering.
My understanding is that the GC mechanism cannot be relied on to properly close an opened file, because this is not portable across different Python interpreters.
I also understand that a close equivalent of RAII is implemented using contexts.
For example, the following with context automatically calls close() when the scope of the with statement ends.
with open(filename, 'w') as ofile:
    # pass
# ofile.close() called automatically (literally, or effectively?)

Does the situation change if after every call to .write(), we follow up with a call to .flush()? In this context, is it still necessary/important/advisable (delete as appropriate) to also explicitly call .close() rather than leaving the open file to be garbage collected later?

This question goes beyond Python. All file operations including writing and closing are send to the OS to be executed. Now every OS and filesystem might handled them differently, but in a normal state (no I/O problems or similar) you should expect that after the end of the with block, a close(), a flush(), or a normal termination of the process your file content should be persisted. Maybe not instantly, but within a short time frame.

If you don't close a file "handle" either explicitly or implicitly (work manager) then you could exhaust the number of allowed open files on your system. For example, the soft limit on MacOS is 1,024. Flushing the file will help to maintain the file's integrity (on disk) but the file remains open as far as Python (and the underlying OS) is concerned

That is true. Does the GC process not cause the file handle to be closed? Most Operating Systems will GC any remaining file handles when a process terminates, but I appreciate this is not behaviour which should be relied on.

@FreelanceConsultant If you open a file in some function, don't close it, then return from the function the variable that held the file handle goes out of scope. It will (at some point) be closed and flushed where appropriate. But you can't be certain when (exactly) that will happen other than when your main program terminates. Best practice is to use with (work manager) then you can be sure that the OS resource(s) will be relinquished and that your file will be intact (assuming you were modifying it)
